# L1 regularization, are early parameters to unfold from 0 weith more relevant?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

As you plot L1 regularization (which seems to be used mostly for its feature selection capabilities) looping through different regularizarion parameters you can see on this graph two specific features jumping into non 0 values quite early on, does this mean that these specific 2 values have more relevance over the model prediction than whichever ones we use in the end?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that if you chose a correspondingly strong regularization parameter those 2 features would be the only ones included in the model, along with their penalized coefficients. You can't always count on such "early parameters" to continue to be the most "relevant" as the regularization parameter becomes less stringent. That depends on the inter-correlations among the features and their relationships with outcome. It's possible for the "relevance" of one of the "early" features to dwindle toward nothingness as other features enter the model.

Note that the "relevance" of features selected by LASSO, in many real-world situations with inter-correlated features, has mostly to do with the predictive power of the model rather than anything "relevant" in a fundamental sense. If you repeat LASSO on multiple bootstrapped samples from your data you will often find the "relevant" features to differ from sample to sample.